# CURL passing parameters from variables - Not working

Tags: linux, shell, url, curl, get

I would like to do a CURL request and pass the following parameters (url-encoded) that I'm reading from a JSON file.

```
curl --data-urlencode ruleId=$ruleId --data-urlencode newLevel=$newLevel --data-urlencode url=$url --data-urlencode urlIsRegex=$urlIsRegex --data-urlencode enabled=$enabled --data-urlencode parameter=$parameter --data-urlencode evidence=$evidence "http://localhost:8090/JSON/alertFilter/action/addGlobalAlertFilter"
```

By running this command I get this error:
`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the syntax of $url match RFC 3986?

Comment: Try quoting all the arguments like `"urlIsRegex=$urlIsRegex"`

Comment: Yes there is the match. Regarding the quoting @Philippe, I tried but I get the same result.